# I am trying to find out if someone is running a server on my Ubuntu without my knowledge

Tags: server, netstat, hacking

I know this sounds a bit odd. But I have been having hacking done on my computer and I am locked out of my "su" user now for some reason. My computer cpu is running abnormally high and I think there may be a server placed on my computer..call me paranoid. How can I tell if there is any server or high usage program put on my computer. I am a newbie in ubuntu so thanks for your understanding. :)

Ps I ran netstat as suggested in an ubuntu post..cant make heads or tails of it..

Comment: If you think someone else has your root password, then delete _everything_ and reinstall _now_.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have been having hacking done on my computer?" If you are wondering if your system has been compromised, then now is the WRONG time to try to learn the skills. Follow @terdon's advice *right now*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`top` should allow you to see processes currently running and you can order them by cpu / memory usage.

- run `top`
- press <kbd>z</kbd> and then <kbd>x</kbd> to see current sort column highlighted
- press <kbd>></kbd> to navigate to CPU column

now you have processes ordered by CPU usage, see if there's anything suspicious

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that your system has been compromised:

1. Take it offline RIGHT NOW.
2. If you are a skilled user, and wish to conduct a detailed forensic investigation at leisure, then clone the drive.
3. Do a clean-install of Ubuntu. Format the disk - delete *everything* and start fresh.
4. Restore your data from backups taken before the suspected intrusion occurred.